# Почему не работает код, нужно сделать клик именно через параметр?

Tags: javascript

При клике на ссылку, ссылка должна исчезнуть, а div появиться.

```js
function myFunction2(obj) {
  var x2 = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
  obj.style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDIV2").style.marginTop = "-20px";
  if (x2.style.display === "block") {
    x2.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x2.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="mybutton" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</a>

<div id="myDIV2">myDIV2</div>
```

Comment: Хочу сделать клик именно через параметр

Comment: Во-первых опечатка в названии функции `myFunction2 - myFunction`, а во-вторых лучше объясни, что именно  хочешь реализовать....

Comment: При клике на кнопку появляется блок с текстом и кнопка изчезает

Comment: В ошибке ведь прямо написано - что нет так, лень посмотреть или перевести?, а код вообще не логичен

Comment: Я правильно понял, при клике на ссылку, ссылка должна исчезнуть, а `div` появиться?

Comment: Да,  всё правильно! Мне нужен вариант этой функции через параметр. (так просят)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var x2 = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
x2.style.display = "none";

function myFunction2(obj) {
  obj.style.display = "none";
  x2.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="mybutton" onclick="myFunction2(this)">Click me</a>

<div id="myDIV2">myDIV2</div>
```